# Leiningen equivalent for maven dependency `type` element

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to follow [this java tutorial for neo4j testing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html), but in Clojure.  I'm using Leiningen for my dependency management, but that tutorial uses maven.  According to the tutorial,  maven would take the following dependency XML:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
   <type>test-jar</type>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

It also says:

> Observe that the test-jar is crucial. Without it you would get the common neo4j-kernel jar, not the one containing the testing facilities.

I was wondering what the equivalent to this would be in my Leiningen project.clj?  Obviously the main bit of it is `[org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel "2.0.0"]` but how do I encode the `type` parameter?

I've tried `[org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel "2.0.0" :type "test-jar"]` but that didn't work (and when I tried using `:type "blah"` it didn't throw an error, so I guess that parameter is ignored by Leiningen).  I've also tried using `:extension` and `:scope` but again, these didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the `:classifier` option is what I wanted:

```
[org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel "2.0.0" :classifier "tests"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`:extension` corresponds to the 'type' attribute e.g.

```
[org.somegroup/artifact "0.1.2" :extension "pom"]
```