# "Cannot find artifact org.openjfx" in leiningen project

Tags: maven, javafx, clojure, leiningen

My Leiningin project cannot find JavaFX in Maven. What did I do wrong?

Here's the command line output (along with some tool version info):

```
> java --version
openjdk 13.0.2 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
> lein --version
Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 13.0.2 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
> lein clean
> lein run
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx:jar:13.0.2 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx:jar:13.0.2 in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

And here is my project file:

```
(defproject pdb-java-client "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [clj-http "2.2.0"]
                 [cheshire "5.6.3"]
                 [local/tsp-dev "6.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/core.match "0.3.0-alpha4"]
                 [org.reflections/reflections "0.9.10"]
                 [org.openjfx/javafx "13.0.2"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot pdb-java-client.core
  :source-paths ["src/clojure"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"]
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Even though this is a Leiningen project, presumably a Maven project would have the same problem since Maven is used under the hood to get the dependencies. I've tried several other `org.openjfx` artifacts and they all fail.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx), there is no release "13.0.2".  However, it appears that "13.0.1" exists:

```
;; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx
[org.openjfx/javafx "13.0.1" :extension "pom"]
```

See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx/13.0.1#leiningen

This works in a demo project:

```
~/expr/demo > lein deps
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Retrieving org/openjfx/javafx/13.0.1/javafx-13.0.1.pom from central
```

I'm not sure about the qualification `:extension "pom"`.  That is left as an exercise for the reader.  ;)

---

**Update**

Found some discussion:

- http://discuss.purelyfunctional.tv/t/maven-headaches/541
- [Leiningen equivalent for maven dependency `type` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790713/leiningen-equivalent-for-maven-dependency-type-element)

Comment: Gluon announced JavaFx 13.0.2 yesterday, it's downloadable from their website. But it hasn't made its way to maven central yet.